# Few JS/CSS fail to load in offline mode while using service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, html5-appcache

Have been trying to test service worker and it works fine while testing on localhost. The same code has been **deployed on server** and few of the **JS and CSS** files are **not** loading in **offline mode**.
But when the page is continuously refreshed, everything loads fine. What could be the probable cause for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

if the serviceworker was already loaded, may be you need to change the version and he will refresh.

Comment: But why few of the files load and few of them fail? Is this anyway related to network?

Comment: There's a lot of reason. Are you sure of your files, have they all the good url?

Comment: yes,  the image loads when I hit the url in the browser

Comment: you have an example?